# I tried creating an centos image vagrant file and the error showed up

Tags: vagrantfile

$ vagrant init geerlingguy/centos7
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.

I tried creating an centos image vagrant file and the error showed up!

Answer (score 0):

An effective solution that worked for me was to enhance the "Path" variable in the Environment Variables by including the path of PowerShell, specifically C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.

Remember to relaunch your preferred command line tool, such as "Git Bash," as it caches system variables to ensure the changes take effect.